# Resolve Promise after child emits event (Vue)

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

So the user makes a request for some data but its prompted with a captcha challenge beforehand... when the challenge is resolved, the captcha component emits an event with a token that needs to go in the request.

My question is: can I use a promise to wait for the challenge to be resolved and then make the request with the token? Can I listen to a child component event like this and then resolve the promise?

If this is not the correct way to handle such situation could anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

I can listen to the child component event with a `v-on:verified` but I want to trigger the challenge when making the request and then continue with it after the captcha is resolved by the user.

```
//component.ts
import captchaComponent from '...';

@Component({
    components: {captchaComponent}
})
@Ref() readonly captcha!: captcha;


function executeCaptchaChallenge(){

    // executes challenge on child component via boolean prop
    this.runChallenge = true;
    const vm = this;


    return new Promise(resolve => {

        vm.captcha.$on('verified', token => {resolve(token)}
})
}


function async getData(){

    const token = await this.executeCaptchaChallenge();
    const response = await axios.post(URL, token);
}
```

```
///component.vue

<template>
    <div>
        <button @click="getData">GET DATA</button>
        <captchaComponent ref="captcha" />
    </div>
</template>

<script src="component.ts"></script>
```

Comment: does it work? obviously you've posted a minimal example with absolutely no error handling, or failed "captcha" handling - though, to be honest, I would not do it like that - adding a Promise seems to make the code more complex than it needs to be - I'd simply have the button `@click` show the captcha, and the `@verified` get the data

Comment: ... since `@verified` event sends the token, you can do `@verified="getData"` and `async function getData(token) { const response = await axios.post(token) }`

Comment: Yes, you can, but don't forget to remove the event listener(s) again after the promise is settled

Comment: @Bergi how can I listen to the child event in the script? I edited the code sample... in this case I get `vm.captcha is undefined`